# Visual Studio won't update properties of my Data Source

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, datasource, objectdatasource

I am using my class "Invoice" as a Data Source. But after adding more properties to it, Visual Studio refuses to refresh the data source and I can't find the new properties in my data source.

Tried restarting project, deleting and adding object as datasource again. Did not work.

Comment: Are you getting an error? If So what is the error message?

Comment: No error. Just won't show the new properties even after refreshing.

Comment: Is the Invoice class in the same assembly as the data source?

Comment: Yes it is. It did update now after i compiled once, but there has to be a better solution?

Comment: Sounds like your intellisense was out of date.  When odd things like this happen the first thing I do is a rebuild.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Problem was Intellisense going out of date due to changes in the Data Source.

Solution was to simply to rebuild the project.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 requires the project to be cleaned and rebuilt every time the data model changes for intellisense to work.

Comment: Had a similar situation with VS2012. The cleaning was required, then the rebuild did the trick.

Comment: In VS2013 Update 3 A rebuild wasn't enough. I had to restart VS.

Comment: I'll second @ElanHasson, needed to rebuild and restart all VS instances.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any source control ? also, `.datasource` file gets created under `Properties` folder, try to remove and re-add the object by opening `Data Sources` tab.

also your new properties in Invoice should have access modifiers (at least `{ get;}` ) otherwise it might not show up AFAIK.

Comment: Where is the `Data Sources` tab?

Answer (score 1):

OMGKurtNilsen is right:

**You don't need to delete and re-create the datasource - a project rebuild will do!**

I tested it with a datasource in a VS 2010 project, that takes its data from a simple C# object.

Answer (score 1):

That problem ocurrs in report designer where use data source object, when i add or remove a property in my class and i refresh the data source in data panel on report data sources, this don't show last changes. I resolved adding reference to Microsoft.CShart assembly. You could try this to resolve you problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your datasource and your form element in different class libraries, sometimes you have to rebuild your class libraries, this situation mostly occurs when the reference bound with static way.

Answer (score 0):

This what you should do.

Refresh the Data Source, Remove the entity and Add it back in before it would change.